Xcode 16 and iOS 18 project not compiling
I updated Xcode and MacOS recently and haven't been able to compile my Flutter app on iOS devices/simulators since then. The error keeps changing every time I run it but here's one of the output in the terminal after running flutter run:
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftGeneratePch emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to
indicate failure


Error (Xcode): no such file or directory:
'/Users/chiragbhansali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation'


Error (Xcode): stat cache file
'/Users/chiragbhansali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator18.0-22A3362-
db63dc9361471f152f572502bdbfe70a.sdkstatcache' not found


Error (Xcode): unable to rename temporary
'/Users/chiragbhansali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/3F9VRK3CXAUUD/UIKit-1KHQ7M05IF
VXC-56601391.pcm.tmp' to output file
'/Users/chiragbhansali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/3F9VRK3CXAUUD/UIKit-1KHQ7M05IF
VXC.pcm': 'No such file or directory'


Error (Xcode): could not build module 'UIKit'
/Users/chiragbhansali/Chirag/Coding/Projects/app/test/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framewo
rk/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:7:8


Error (Xcode): could not build module 'Flutter'
/Users/chiragbhansali/Chirag/Coding/Projects/app/test/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8


Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header
'/Users/chiragbhansali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eifcguceazlwumgsyzegclqdrbqt/Build/Intermed
iates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_PB6A5GFLTNPC-clang_3F9VRK3CXAUUD.pch' for
bridging header
'/Users/chiragbhansali/Chirag/Coding/Projects/app/test/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'


Uncategorized (Xcode): Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit
code to indicate failure


Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftEmitModule failed with a nonzero exit code


Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 16 Pro.


What I have tried so far:

Deleting iOS SDK and simulators
Cleaning Xcode build cache using cmd+shift+k
Creating a new Flutter project and trying to compile it (it failed so that reduces the chances of it being a Flutter issue)
Clearing the DerivedData folder
Clearing settings and cache of simulators
Restarting laptop

Versions:

Xcode: 16.0
iOS: 18.0
MacOS: 15.1 (didn't work with 15.0 either)
Flutter: 3.24


I have found a workaround - change the location of DerivedData folder in Xcode Workspace settings (File -> Workspace Settings) to something else.
